# Implementing a method with generics relating the return and parameter types specified in an interface that does not do this

Tags: java, generics, visitor-pattern

I am with a sort of trouble when using java generics in the visitor pattern.

My code is something like that:

```
public interface MyInterfaceVisitor<A, B> {
    public A visitMyConcreteObject(MyConcreteObject object, B parameter);
}

public interface MyObject {
    public <A, B> A accept(MyInterfaceVisitor<A, B> visitor, B parameter);
}

public class MyConcreteObject implements MyObject {
    @Override
    public <A, B> A accept(MyInterfaceVisitor<A, B> visitor, B parameter) {
        return visitor.visitMyConcreteObject(this, parameter);
    }
}

public class MyConcreteVisitor implements MyInterfaceVisitor<????> {

    @Override
    public <X extends C> X visitMyConcreteObject(MyConcreteObject object, Class<X> parameter) {
        // Do a lot of things.
        // Return an instance of the given class.
    }

    // This method is the entry point of the MyConcreteVisitor.
    public <X extends C> void someOtherMethod(Class<X> parameter) {
        MyObject m = ...;
        X x = m.accept(this, parameter);
        ...;
    }
}

public class C {}
public class Dog extends C {}
public class Cat extends C {}

public class Client {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        MyConcreteVisitor v = new MyConcreteVisitor();
        v.someOtherMethod(Cat.class);
        v.someOtherMethod(Dog.class);
    }
}

// We have other implementations of the visitor that does not matters, like this one.
public class SomeOtherConcreteVisitor implements MyInterfaceVisitor<String, Integer> {
    @Override
    public String visitMyConcreteObject(MyConcreteObject object, Integer parameter) {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

I need to find what is the generic signature in the ???? that makes the code compilable allowing the overriden method in MyConcreteVisitor class to match the signature in MyInterfaceVisitor interface.

I can't change the signature of the visitMyObject in the MyInterfaceVisitor interface, nor its generics. This happens because others implementations of MyInterfaceVisitor exists and their generics have nothing to with the ones from MyConcreteVisitor.

The MyConcreteVisitor class should not have a generic per-se, so the compiler must allow a `MyConcreteVisitor v = new MyConcreteVisitor();` without generating the unchecked or rawtypes warning.

If I change the concrete visitMyObject to `public C visitMyObject(MyObject object, Class<? extends C> parameter)` and declare the ???? as `<C, Class<? extends C>>`, I would need to add a cast in the someOtherMethod.

How to define the generic type making it compilable without getting the unchecked or rawtypes warning, changing the interface or adding a cast? Is this even possible in java or I am abusing the generics too much?

Comment: is B always supposed to be the class describing A?  if so, you should only have a single generic parameter A, not A and B.

Comment: So is the entry point to this system supposed to be calling `someOtherMethod`?  Is `X` supposed to be a concrete type or a generic type?

Comment: @matts. I added the <X> in the someOtherMethod to make that clear. Sorry, for forgeting that.

Comment: @jtahlborn I edited the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your implementation is trying to introduce another type parameter `X extends C` to the method `visitMyConcreteObject` and resolve the `B` parameter with it. You can't make `visitMyConcreteObject` generic with `X` but try to resolve `B` with a type parameterized by `X`, e.g. `Class<X>`, because `B` is resolved at the class declaration but `X` is only declared by a method of the class.

From what I can see, you have two options. Either make `MyConcreteVisitor` generic on `X`:

```
public class MyConcreteVisitor<X extends C> implements MyInterfaceVisitor<X, Class<X>> {

    @Override
    public X visitMyConcreteObject(MyConcreteObject object, Class<X> parameter) {
        // Do a lot of things.
        // Return an instance of the given class.
    }
}
```

Or get rid of `X` and lose type safety (beyond the concrete type `C`):

```
public class MyConcreteVisitor implements MyInterfaceVisitor<C, Class<? extends C>> {

    @Override
    public C visitMyConcreteObject(MyConcreteObject object, Class<? extends C> parameter) {
        // Do a lot of things.
        // Return an instance of the given class.
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear. See the public static void main method. It basically says that your first approach would not work. Your second approach is what will force me to add a cast in the someOtherMethod method, and for now it looks like the best option.

Comment: You are basically saying that my problem is unsolvable and that the java generics is not powerful enough to express what I am intending, losing some type information somewhere. Is that correct?

Comment: The first approach would work if you settled for using or extending `MyConcreteVisitor<Cat>` and `MyConcreteVisitor<Dog>`. "Not powerful enough" - perhaps. Like I said, you're trying to introduce a new type parameter to the *method*, but bound the *class* to it. I suspect that doesn't make sense even on an academic level, beyond Java.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what you are looking for:

```
public class MyConcreteVisitor implements MyInterfaceVisitor<Object,Class<?>> {

    @Override
    public Object visitMyConcreteObject(MyConcreteObject object, Class<?> parameter) {
        // Do a lot of things.
        // Return an instance of the given class.
    }

    // This method is the entry point of the MyConcreteVisitor.
    public <X> void someOtherMethod(Class<X> parameter) {
        MyObject m = ...;
        X x = parameter.cast(m.accept(this, parameter));
        ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that. Basically, only in that visitor A is related to B. There are other visitors where it isn't.